# What are acceptable permissions for ActivityCompat.requestPermissions() to request?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, permissions, android-permissions

In my Android app using Java, I define a `checkForPermission()` method to check the grant status of a single permission. If the permission has not already been granted, it requests this permission from the user using `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()`.

Here is the method:

```
private boolean checkForPermission(String permission, int rationaleMessageId, int requestCode) {

    // Check if permission is already granted.
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Permission has not been granted. Check if a rationale AlertDialog should be shown.
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, permission)) {

            // Show rationale AlertDialog explaining why this permission is needed.
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle(R.string.rationale_dialog_title)
                    .setMessage(rationaleMessageId)
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                    // Request permission again.
                                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{permission}, requestCode);
                                }
                            })
                    .create()
                    .show();
        }

        // Do not show rationale AlertDialog. Just request permission again.
        else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{permission}, requestCode);
        }
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

I've noticed that the method works perfectly fine for simple permissions such as `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, but does not work for more dangerous permissions such as `android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS`.

I'm wondering which types of permissions `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()` may actually request. My assumption is that dangerous permissions must be requested using other means, but I would like any feedback I can get on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifically, `requestPermissions()` is used for permissions with a `protectionLevel` of `dangerous`.

`WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` [is `dangerous`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE). [`WRITE_SETTINGS` is not](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#WRITE_SETTINGS).

Comment: @CommSo use requestPermissions() for dangerous permissions, use other means for signature permissions, and don't request for normal permissions?

Comment: @DavidRead: "use requestPermissions() for dangerous permissions" -- correct. "don't request for normal permissions?" -- correct.  "use other means for signature permissions" -- the details of permissions other than `normal` and `dangerous` vary a bit. Usually, the documentation will provide instructions, such as [in the JavaDocs for `WRITE_SETTINGS`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#WRITE_SETTINGS).